# What is a mental framework to understand how effects will be executed?

Tags: clojure

What is a mental framework to understand how effects will be executed?
For example, I can't understand why in this case

```
(take 5 (map prn (range 10)))
```

REPL prints 10 numbers

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

& in other case

```
    (transduce (comp (take 5)
                     (map prn))
            conj
            []
            (range 10))
```

it prints only 5

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

but we have `take 5` in both examples?

Comment: ... Do you understand what does `take 5` mean?

Comment: Try using debugger (if I understand the question correctly).

Comment: @user202729 I think I got it, basically `(take 5)` is applied before `(map prn)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Your first snippet `(take 5 (map prn (range 10)))` is actually giving you 5 results.**

Here's the REPL example of `(map prn [])` which gives you `LazySeq` of length 10. And it contains `nil` thats what `prn` function returns.

```
user=> (map prn (range 10))
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
(nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil)
```

Then when you apply `(take 5 )` on above `LazySeq`, you get 5 `nil`s.

```
user=> (def some-data (map prn (range 10)))
#'user/some-data
user=> (take 5 some-data)
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
(nil nil nil nil nil)
```

If you don't believe yet, print the size,

```
user=> (count (take 5 some-data))
5
```

**You might want to read docs as well,**

```
user=> (doc take)
-------------------------
clojure.core/take
([n] [n coll])
  Returns a lazy sequence of the first n items in coll, or all items if
  there are fewer than n.  Returns a stateful transducer when
  no collection is provided.
nil
```

**2) And in your second snippet you are saying `take 5` first then apply `prn`, thats why its printing only 5 elements.**

```
user=> (def tform (comp (take 5) (map prn)))
#'user/tform

user=> (transduce tform conj [] (range 10))
0
1
2
3
4
[nil nil nil nil nil]
```

To better understand it see following example to filter odd numbers, (modified little bit than [official `transduce` example](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/transduce))

```
user=> (def xform (comp (take 5) (filter odd?)))
#'user/xform

user=> (transduce xform conj (range 1 100))
[1 3 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood something. The `prn` function just prints a value returning `nil`:

```
user=> (prn 42)
42
nil
```

Thus, when applying it to a collection, you will just print all the items receiving a sequence of `nil`s as the result:

```
user=> (map prn (range 10))
0
1
...
8
9
(nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil)
```

The `take` function returns a subsequence collecting the next item until it becomes less then provided value. Since all the `nil`s are less then `5`, all the items will be returned.

The second example suffers from the same mistakes. Please read the documentation carefully.

There are also some general notes: do not use `prn` or any related functions (`pr`, `prn-str` and others) when dealing with collections. Print only the final results. Your code should be free from side effects. Use REPL to evaluate particular fragments of your code. Decompose threading macro on separate functions then it grows. But do not use prints.